# Registering a dll file on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, dll

I have a program file (*Calculator.exe*) which when I want to run it, it says:

*The program can't start because MSVCP110D.dll is missing from your computer.                        Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.*

I downloaded the *msvcp110d.dll* (32bit) and tried to register it using this command:

*C:\Windows\system32>regsvr32 C:\Users\CS\Desktop\msvcp110d.dll*
on an elevated cmd on my Windows 7 x64.
But caught the following message (the screenshot).

I also uninstalled and reinstalled these programs:
*vcredist.x86 (2010)

vcredist.x86 (2012)

vcredist.x64 (2012)

vcredist.x86 (2013)

vcredist.x64 (2013)

vcredist.x86 (2015)

vcredist.x64 (2015)*

But no change happened!
How to solve the issue please?

[image: *enter image description here*]

Comment: Do you have Google's NIK Collection installed? also have you tried running sfc /scannow in an elevated command prompt

Comment: Please take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/778589/how-to-fix-the-missing-msvcp110-dll. The point is: "The correct course of action here is not to go downloading random dll files from all of the internet but instead work out just which Visual C++ Runtime your program is expecting and install that."

Comment: If you have the source code to this application you can also recompile it in release mode.  This will allow it to reference the non-debug version of MSVCP110.dll

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I have it but compiling it in Release mode causes errors on visual studio.

Comment: Those errors are a seperate question.

Answer (score 3):

All you should need to do is place that DLL file into the same folder as the executable.  That way, the application does not have to rely on the DLL being registered in order to find it.  MSVC DLLs are not COM objects so registering them is not necessary as long as they are in a place where the application can find it.

Comment: Yes, I agree and it works that way. I thank you and +1. What do you mean by "COM objects" please?

Comment: COM objects are DLLs that provide an interface for other software to use without having to be written in the same language or even be linked against it. For example, Excel provides a COM object called Excel.Application that you can use to manipulate Excel spreadsheets from a scripting language like Python. COM objects must be registered with a name and the functions they provide. In your case, however, this Calculator.exe file was compiled in MSVC++ and was directly linked against that DLL. It is not a COM object so it doesn't need to be registered.

Answer (score 1):

MSVCP110**D** is the DEBUG version of the C++ redistributables, which means the program you're trying to use was complied in Debug mode installed of Release mode. Not a good sign. :/

Since v11.0 is VS 2012, you can probably (properly) obtain the debug DLL by downloading and installing the Debugging Tools for VS 2012, aka [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38184).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I downloaded and installed _rtools_setup_x64_ but the problem still exists!

Comment: As Wes suggests in ihs answer, try just dupming the file in quesiton into the same folder as Calculator.exe.